# convert string to XML in eclipse XML editor

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin

I'm using eclipse with XML Editor

I copy below

```
 &lt;suite name="myTest Suite" &gt;

 &lt;test name="web" &gt;

 &lt;classes&gt; &lt;class name="TesScripts.T005TimeSheet" /&gt;

 &lt;/classes&gt;

 &lt;/test&gt;

 &lt;/suite&gt;
```

and need to convert it to

```
<suite name="my Test Suite" >

    <test name="web" >

        <classes> <class name="TesScripts.T005TimeSheet" />

        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

how can i do it with eclipse..currently doing with notepad++ plugins copy&past. 
do i need more tools (plug ins) or could it be done with eclipse and XML Editor?

searching in web was not success.

Comment: Are you looking for something more sophisticated than find and replace? If nothing more, it's still a text editor with all of the text editing features.

Comment: In notepad ++ you have addons for pretty print and converting &lt,&gl to <>...i'm looking for that.